# search for any number in SOLR

Tags: solr

How can I set up a SOLR index in a way that allows me to search for any number?

I believe that the following works, more or less:

0* OR 1* OR 2* OR 3* OR 4* OR 5* OR 6* OR 7* OR 8* OR 9*

But it really does not seem to be ideal, and cannot be used as part of double-quoted expressions, etc.

Comment: So what are you looking for? Any document that contains at least one number?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for all documents that contain a token that just is a number, a regular expression search should work:

```
q=field:/[0-9]+/
```

If you have tokens in your text that contain a number within other characters (.. but those wouldn't have matched your example), you can add a wildcard before and after matching the numbers:

```
q=field:/.*[0-9]+.*/
```

Comment: I had no idea regular expression search existed, thank you. I will test the solution you are proposing.

Comment: Tested, works (though might not be performant enough for what I am trying to do), thank you!

Comment: When performance is an issue, do it when you're indexing instead of when querying. Extract all numbers to a separate field with a `copyField` instruction and a field type with a  `PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory` that replaces anything that isn't a number or a space.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I need to search for all documents that have a number close to a certain term. The following works: {!complexphrase inOrder=false}title:"something /[0-9]+/"~10

Comment: But it does not perform well. I think I need to create a custom token for all numbers. I have no idea how to do that though.

Comment: You can use a patternreplacefilter to replace [0-9]+ with just a hardcoded string such as NUMBER, then search for `title:"something NUMBER"~10`

Comment: I will try that! Thank you!

Comment: Be careful to use a token that wouldn't occur naturally in the text to avoid giving false hits.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess I will use something like nnnuuummm